# Database Migration is getting failed due to NLOG.config in Visual Studio 2022 Mac

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nlog, visual-studio-mac-2022

I started programming with Visual Studio 2022 in Mac M1. I am developing an application with .net core 6 and initially I used to develop in Windows. I copied my project and started to work in VS 2022 Mac. While doing the DB Migration (Using dotnet CLI) I am getting error and it's getting failed due to NLog.config. I am using NLog for the logging functionality.

DataAccess layer and WepAPI are separate project in a solution.DBContextClass and migration scripts are present in DataAccess Layer and the connection string is present in WebAPI.

Error while doing the db migration:

> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.65 Build succeeded. dotnet exec --depsfile
> /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI.deps.json
> --additionalprobingpath /Users/MASKED/.nuget/packages --runtimeconfig /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI.runtimeconfig.json
> /Users/MASKED/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/6.0.7/dotnet-ef/6.0.7/tools/net6.0/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll
> database update -c ApplicationDbContext --assembly
> /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess.dll
> --project /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess.csproj
> --startup-assembly /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI.dll
> --startup-project /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI.csproj
> --project-dir /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess/
> --root-namespace MyCoreApplication.DataAccess --language C# --framework net6.0 --nullable --working-dir /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess
> --verbose Using assembly 'MyCoreApplication.DataAccess'. Using startup assembly 'MyCoreApplicationWebAPI'. Using application base
> '/Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0'.
> Using working directory
> '/Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI'.
> Using root namespace 'MyCoreApplication.DataAccess'. Using project
> directory
> '/Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplication.DataAccess/'.
> Remaining arguments: . Finding DbContext classes... Finding
> IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations... Finding application
> service provider in assembly 'MyCoreApplicationWebAPI'... Finding
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider... Using environment
> 'Development'. NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when loading
> configuration
> /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/nlog.config
> ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
> System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()    at
> NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader,
> String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at
> NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader,
> String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)    at
> NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader reader, String
> fileName, LogFactory logFactory)    at
> NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.LoadXmlLoggingConfiguration(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String configFile, LogFactory logFactory)    at
> NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.LoadXmlLoggingConfigurationFile(LogFactory
> logFactory, String configFile)    at
> NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.TryLoadLoggingConfiguration(LogFactory
> logFactory, String configFile, LoggingConfiguration& config)    at
> NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.Load(LogFactory logFactory,
> String filename)    at
> NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationWatchableFileLoader.Load(LogFactory
> logFactory, String filename)    at
> NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile, Boolean optional)
> at NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)    at
> NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)    at
> Program.$(String[] args) in
> /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/Program.cs:line
> 25
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.CreateHost()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0(String[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__3(String[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.AppServiceProviderFactory.CreateFromHosting(String[]
> args)
> ***An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Exception when loading configuration
> /Users/MASKED/Projects/MyCoreApplication/MyCoreApplicationWebAPI/nlog.config***
> No application service provider was found. Finding DbContext classes
> in the project... Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to
> create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyCoreApplication.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyCoreApplication.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
> factory)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
> contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action)
> ***Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.*** For the different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: Can you share your NLog.config file?

Comment: can you please share your mail address to share the file.

Comment: i don't want you to send it to me. if it's something that you can't share publicly, just try to find the parsing problem with nlog.config itself. maybe it's not correctly formatted, or, maybe it's not correctly configured. replace it with a minimal nlog.config file and see if you still get the error etc.